# How to make load tests for bot on Pyrogram?

Tags: mocking, load-testing, pyrogram

I created a bot on BotFather and wrote code for it in Pyrogram. There is a rather complex logic with a lot of functions and I am looking for an opportunity to conduct load testing of the bot, but I do not understand how it can be carried out.
As an option, I tried to create mock testing of updates, but by simulating an update through MTProto protocol, it turns out that the bot is talking to itself, which is obviously not the right testing...
So I didn't find something about good bot testing, especially for bot on Pyrogram.

I will be really pleasant for useful tips and good examples.

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions before using unrelated tags.

Comment: @CallMeStag I fixed it, thank you!
Do you know smth related to my question?

Answer (score 0):

As per [Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api)

> The Bot API is an **HTTP-based interface** created for developers keen on building bots for Telegram.

so you need to choose a [load testing tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools) which supports [HTTP protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) and conduct some load onto your bot [entry point webhook](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/six-easy-steps-to-create-a-telegram-bot-from-a-google-spreadsheet-b62008d2b81f).

It will mimic your Bot real life usage and you will be able to get some metrics like response time, throughput, etc.

Comment: So it doesn't matter at all that basically everything is written using pyrogram? Is it still necessary to test via http requests? I tried to do this, but it turns out that the bot sends requests to itself, and not as if it communicates with the user, which is why the corresponding errors appear, for example, when sending files to the dialog (to itself)

Comment: Moreover, my bot on Pyrogram hasn't got webhooks so far